# haproxy acl to filter tcp request based on client IP taken from PROXY protocl v2 headers

Tags: acl, haproxy

So we have an AWS setup with NLB so that we can attach it to EIP and thus be static for customer whitelisting.
NLB sends Proxy Protocol v2 headers to haproxy which sends it back to the backend servers.
The app is picking this up and uses it.
The issue that I am trying to figure out is that since haproxy gets the internal IP of the NLB and it gets public client IP only through PROXY protocol header,

how can I parse client IP from PROXY header and filter it based on whitelisting ACL in haproxy?

I have a listen configuration like this

```
listen backoffice
  bind 10.2.3.4:443 accept-proxy
  mode tcp
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 3 error-limit 1 on-error mark-down
  option  tcplog
  acl network_allowed src 5.6.7.8 1.4.6.8 4.6.7.8
  tcp-request connection reject if !network_allowed
  server backoffice.prod.local 10.1.2.3:443 check-send-proxy send-proxy-v2-ssl-cn  port 443
```

THIS ^^ breaks the haproxy for this backend  - it works only if I comment the tcp-request line and reload

To me, this looks like quite useful use case but so far no online research has shown any promising haproxy configuration to do just that.

I have only less than 2 days to figure this out so let's hope the community can lend a hand in a short time

Comment: Are the acl network_allowed src addresses the "real" client ips you wanted to allow, or load balancers? I assume so, based on the question, but the text is not super-obvious.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring it out for my case :)

working config is this :

```
listen backoffice
  bind 10.2.3.4:443 accept-proxy
  mode tcp
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 3 error-limit 1 on-error mark-down
  option  tcplog
  acl network_allowed src 5.6.7.8 1.4.6.8 4.6.7.8
  tcp-request content reject if !network_allowed
  server backoffice.prod.local 10.1.2.3:443 check port 443
```

I removed the part where proxy headers are passed to backend as it did not need them.
I only needed to have NLB pass proxy header to haproxy so that we can reliably filter on source/ client IP